# VBA Macro Excel: How to read a Unicode character from Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba, unicode, cell

I am struggling to read a Unicode character back from a cell in VBA Excel.

```
Sub mySub()
    Cells(1, "A").Value = ChrW(10003)   ' Writes checkbox symbol to A1

    MsgBox Asc(Cells(1, "A").Value)     ' Output:  63 (questionmark symbol)
                                        ' Expected Output: 10003
End Sub
```

I need to read the Unicode character to see, if the checkbox symbol was modified by a user. I have no Idea how to compare a Unicode character with the cells value..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes all you need is second pair of eyes. :)

```
Sub mySub()
    Cells(1, "A").Value = ChrW(10004)   ' Writes checkbox symbol to A1

    'MsgBox Asc(Cells(1, "A").Value)     ' Output:  63 (questionmark symbol)
                                   ' Expected Output: 10003
    '/ Works! 
    MsgBox AscW(Cells(1, "A").Value2)    'Almost there. Use AscW instead of Asc
End Sub
```